# Android не корректная работа action bar menu

Tags: java, android, actionbar, menu

Доброго времени суток.

У меня в приложении есть класс `MainMenu`, который содержит *боковое меню* и `FrameLayout` для отображения фрагментов, один из фрагментов содержит `ViewPager`, который наполнен фрагментами. Один из этих фрагментов имеет свое *action bar menu*, если я нажимаю на пункт тулбара, а затем открываю *боковое меню* и перехожу на другой фрагмент, то в этом фрагменте, при нажатии на пункт тулбара, выполняются действия из `OnOptionsItemSelected` старого фрагмента. Это показывает даже отладка.

В каждом фрагменте при отрисовке вызываю `menu.clear()`. Иконки отображаются верно, но действия при нажатии выполняются не те.

Вот так выглядит обработка меню тулбара в любом из фрагментов:

```
public class MyBodyPhoto extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return v;
}


private View.OnClickListener photoClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(canDelete)
            showPhotoToDelete((ImageView) view, (boolean)view.getTag());
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    //    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    if(canDelete){
        addPhotoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        MenuItem conf = menu.add("Подтвердить");
        conf.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_save);
        conf.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        MenuItem cancel = menu.add("Отменить");
        cancel.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);
        cancel.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        ((MainMenu)
getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Выбрано: " +       imagesToDelete.size());

    }
    else{

        MenuItem mi = menu.add("Удалить");
        mi.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_delete);
        mi.setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        ((MainMenu)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Мое тело");

    }

    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    CharSequence title = item.getTitle();

    if (title.equals("Отменить")) {
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        canDelete = !canDelete;
    } else {// if (title.equals("Редактировать")) {
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        canDelete = !canDelete;
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решена, при создании фрагментов внутри другого фрагмента вместо `getFragmentManager()` нужно использовать `getChildFragmentManager()`.